# How onDraw method works in subclass of android-custom-view class?

Tags: android, subclass, drawable, ondraw, android-custom-view

I facing problem to draw rectangle at subclass of my android custom view class. Each time super class onDraw method works.But subclass onDraw method never executed. Super class will draw a rectangle and subclass will draw 4 rectangle within the super-class drawn rectangle.I can't fixed this problem.please help me.

Here is my sample code.

**SuperClass:**

```
public class ColorFanView extends View{

    public ShapeDrawable[] mDrawables;

    public ColorFanView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);    
    }
    public ColorFanView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);  
    }
    public ColorFanView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvasObject) {
        super.onDraw(canvasObject);
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        int width = 80;
        int height = 200;
        Paint thePaint = new Paint();   
        thePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        RectF rectnagle1 = new RectF(x,y,x+width,y+height);
        canvasObject.drawRoundRect(rectnagle1, 10.0f, 10.0f, thePaint);     
    }
}
```

**Subclass:**

```
public class ColorFanStack extends ColorFanView{

    public ColorFanStack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    public ColorFanStack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public ColorFanStack(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }
    public void initView() {

        mDrawables = new ShapeDrawable[4];
        float[] outerR1 = new float[] { 12, 12, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        mDrawables[0] = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR1, null, null));
        mDrawables[0].getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        mDrawables[1] = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        mDrawables[1].getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        mDrawables[2] = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        mDrawables[2].getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mDrawables[3] = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        mDrawables[3].getPaint().setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvasObj) {
        super.onDraw(canvasObj);
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        int width = 80;
        int height = 40;
        int canvasSpace =5;
        for (Drawable dr : mDrawables) {
            dr.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            dr.draw(canvasObj);
            y += height + canvasSpace;
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myViewGroup" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.test.colorfan.ColorFanView
        android:layout_width="200dip" android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:id="@+id/firstView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*Please help me regarding this issue. Hopefully, I will get a reply soon.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your layout (please edit the question to include your layout), is defining your ColorFanView instances in such a way that they have 0 height or width; therefore, the parent View does not draw them.

EDIT 7/27/2011: Habibur Rahman added his layout XML to the question. This is the new answer:

Your two classes work, but you added the wrong one to your layout (you should have used `ColorFanStack` instead of `ColorFanView`). An instance of `ColorFanStack` will inherit the drawing of `ColorFanView` (by virtue of the fact that your `ColorFanStack.onDraw()` method calls `super.onDraw()`). I think that that was the behavior that you were trying to achieve.

Here is the XML that I used with the classes as you defined them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <com.habecker.demo.ColorFanStack
        android:layout_width="200dip" android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:id="@+id/secondView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my xml file.Is it right way? Does subclass of ColorFanView work as child view class? Can I called a custom view inside another custom view class?

Comment: @Habibur Rahman Got it; see the additional information that I added to the answer.